# Gas form of vs. Gaseous form of

Tags: word-usage

I'm writing a report for school, and I'm wondering if I should say:

> the **gas** form of oxygen

or:

> the **gaseous** form of oxygen

Which one would be the better choice and why?

Comment: The second: [**gaseous**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/gaseous). You might just say **gas** in everyday speech but this is a science project?

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical in U.S. English. It is, however, more idiomatic to use an adjective, when one is available, to modify a noun than to use a noun to modify a noun. So I'd use

> gaseous oxygen

as a parallel to

> solid oxygen.

Comment: More usual is **liquid oxygen**.

Comment: It is, but I was not really thinking of what is commercially available.

Comment: There's even [_metallic oxygen_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_oxygen#Metallic_oxygen). Insofar as this question goes, we could point out how that works better than _metal oxygen_. (Either one might make a good band name, though.)

Comment: @JR That's funny.